# Java. Запуск приложение на 32-х битной JVM. Параметр -d32

Tags: java

Привет. Понадобилось запустить 32-х разрядное приложение на 64 бит системе (Windows 8.1)
Установил 32 bit JRE.
Но с флагом -d32 приложение запустить не удалось:

```
javaw -d32 -jar myJar.jar
```

> Error: this Java instance does not support a 32 bit JVM. Please install the desired version

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Какова необходимость запуска Java-приложения в 32-битном окружении? В нём используются вызовы Windows API 32-бит?

Answer (score 1):

> Как решить эту проблему?

например, так, как предложено в сообщении об ошибке:

> Please install the desired version

т.е., установить желаемую версию [jvm](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine).

а потом **именно её** и [запускать](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5272216/4827341).